# Possibility of converting a PDF containing equations to MOBI

Tags: pdf, conversion, mobi

I have a PDF with lots of equations which gets distorted when converted to MOBI format using Calibre. Is there any reliable way of doing that? The equations in the PDF might have been written using LaTeX or any other software which I do not have any idea of.

Comment: No - you need the original. - You can convert the other way - pdf is basically a printed book, mobi/epub are in a markup language that can be processed into something that looks good.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I have about 7 years experience converting from PDF to plain text then to Markdown, which I can convert to HTML or most anything else using Pandoc. https://pandoc.org

A PDF is an endpoint, it is difficult to convert from PDF to anything. If you do find a tool, it is likely it would not be free, it would be a paid tool.

If you are able to extract the text from a PDF the math equations will likely be mangled and you will still have to do a lot of hand editing. There are free sites to do this but most of them have limits as to the size of the input PDF or the number of pages they will convert (for free), and the output is inconsistent.

**Starting with a PDF is usually a bad idea, because it requires lots of hand editing after extracting the text.**

1. Also, what will you do if the math equation is too wide to fit on the MOBI reader screen? Will the font shrink it to fit the screen? Will it then be too small to read? Will the equation get cut off if it is not shrunken? What does every major different reader do in this case?
2. MOBI is the older format. Why are you using that? What is the specific requirement that says you must use MOBI?
3. Can you change the equations to images and plop them into the MOBI file?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/download/ or `FineReader`. You'll likely get a usable but bad result.